# How to set image in the frame in opencv?

Tags: opencv

I have written a piece of code to capture and store image in opencv and python. When I pass camera index of my webcam of laptop, the captured image occupies total space of window of image.But when I pass camera index of externally connected wabcam,the captured image doesn't occupy whole window,instead when I open image,it appears at the centre of window. But I want image to occupy whole window.Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use opencv [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) class to set Camera parameter like frame width, frame height etc...

See below example...

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, New_WIDTH);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, New_HEIGHT);
```